# MVC call ActionMethod with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

In this code, I want the `ControlloQualitaTurno` to call the `ListTurno(string KTurnoTime = null, string startDate = null)`, but instead always the `ListTurno()` without parameters gets called.

What is wrong?

```
public class RapportiController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult ListTurno()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult ListTurno(string KTurnoTime = null, string startDate = null)
    {
        // Query database ...

        return View(listRRVM);
    }

    public RedirectToRouteResult ControlloQualitaTurno()
    {
        // Get values from somewhere ...
        string codiceTurno = ...
        string startDateTurno = ...

        // ...and pass them to List action method via RouteValueDictionary
        RouteValueDictionary dic = new RouteValueDictionary();
        dic.Add("KTurnoTime", codiceTurno);
        dic.Add("startDate", startDateTurno);

        return RedirectToAction(actionName: "ListTurno", controllerName: "Rapporti", routeValues: dic);
    }

}
```

Comment: `RedirectToAction`, returns an __HTTP 302__ response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a __GET__ request to the specified action. __Thus get action is getting called.__

Comment: Yes, but... I was sure the code was calling the [Post] method before I did some changes... Probably the [HttpGet] method wasn't there?!... However If I remove it now I get an: HTTP 404. The resource cannot be found. Requested URL: /Rapporti/ListTurno ...

Description:

Comment: Try with removing verbs, `[HttpGet] and [HttpPost]`, if you remove get method get method and have `[HttpPost]` thus your are getting error

Comment: Yes!! it is the verbs... I removed them and all is working agains, thanks

Comment: Glad Its working. Great :)